# How to update serial number text in recyclerview items in real time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that displays a series of numbers at the beginning of each list item as shown below.

[image]

I did this by getting the position of the item on the list and adding one.

**onBindViewHolder**

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(item!!, clickListener)
    holder.numberTextView.text = position.plus(1).toString()
}
```

I want the numbers to update in real time when I delete an item on the list. As of now, when I delete items in the recyclerview, I get a list as shown below. I have to refresh the layout to get a sequential numbered list. How do I go about updating the numbers in real time.

[image]

**My Adapter**

```
    class Adapter( 
       private val clickListener: ClickListener) :
ListAdapter<DataItems, Adapter.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataItems>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DataItems, newItem: DataItems): Boolean {
        return oldItem.itemId == newItem.itemId
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: OrderSummary, newItem: OrderSummary): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

fun getItemAtPosition(position: Int): DataItems {
    return getItem(position)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(item!!, clickListener)
    holder.umberTextView.text = position.plus(1).toString()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    val numberTextView = binding.orderItemListNumber

    fun bind(
        item: DataItems,
        clickListener: SummaryItemListener
    ) {
        binding.clickListener = clickListener
        binding.DataItems= item
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding =
                ItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}
```

}

How I delete an item:

```
    override fun onSwiped(
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, 
         direction: Int) {
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                val toast: Toast =
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "1 item removed: ${item.name}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                toast.show()
          viewModel.delete(item) // Method to delete item from database
         }
```

**Delete method in ViewModel**

```
    fun delete(summary: OrderSummary) {
    uiScope.launch {
        deleteItem(summary)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun deleteItem(orderSummary: OrderSummary) {
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.delete(orderSummary)
        }
    }
```

Comment: After deleting an item, using Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); should be sufficient in your case.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work well with DiffUtil :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the item from the list by sending it position from `RecyclerView`, once you did it, the item's position will be updated.

You can do it by make the list in your class seen by the adapter as it can remove from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using index of item instead of position in `onBindViewHolder()` so that it looks like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, 
position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    val index = getCurrentList().indexOf(item)
    holder.bind(item!!, clickListener)
    holder.umberTextView.text = 
    index.plus(1).toString()
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It more or less works the same as it did before. How can I observe for changes to the index, like using observer methods or LiveData?

Comment: Show us your deleteItem (or something like that) method.

Comment: You are using `ViewModel` and `ListAdapter`, so you should use `LiveData` as well and observe it in your `Activity` / `Fragment`. Whenever you receive a `List<DataItems>` in `onChanged()`, you can call `ListAdapter.submitList()`  and rest will all be handled by the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, then the RecyclerView rebinds and redraws every item in the list, including items that are not visible on the screen. This is not optimal. If the list is large, then using DiffUtil is desirable.
If we use DiffUtil, then when deleting a list item, your DiffUtil does not see the difference between some new and old items. Therefore, `onBindViewHolder(..)` is not called for all visible list items.
Therefore, the code:

```
holder.umberTextView.text = position.plus(1).toString()
```

for some elements does not work.

Possible solution:

```
@Entity(tableName = "data_item_table")
    data class DataItem(
    
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var itemId: Long = 0L,
       
        var fieldOne: Long = 0L,        
    
        // !!! This field is not stored in the database, but is filled in YoursViewModel
        @Ignore
        var sequentialNumber: Int = 0
    
    )
    
    //-------------------------
        
    class YoursViewModel(private val dataSource: YoursDatabaseDao) : ViewModel() {
    
        private val dataItemsWhereSequentialNumberIsZero = dataSource.getAllDataItems()
    
        // !!! Here we set the actual sequential number
        val dataItems =
            Transformations.map(dataItemsWhereSequentialNumberIsZero ) { dataItems ->    
                var i = 0
                dataItems.forEach {
                    it.sequentialNumber = ++i
                }
                dataItems
            }
    
        fun deleteById(dataItemId: Long) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                dataSource.deleteById(dataItemId)
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------------------
    @Dao
    interface YoursDatabaseDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM data_item_table ORDER BY itemId ASC")
        fun getAllDataItems(): LiveData<List<DataItem>>
    }
```

In an activity or fragment, subscribe to LiveDate dataItems